# config.ini file properties being replaced by another file properties in OSGI Run Time

Tags: java, eclipse, proxy, osgi

I have an option in my config.ini file to set proxy settings in my OSGI application, eg:
***http:proxyHost= 192.168......***

However, when I set them, out of nowhere in "org.eclipse.core.net.prefs" file they are overridden, eg:
**proxyData/http/host=something else ...**

I am wondering whether somehow eclipse thinks that I am trying to reconfigure its own proxy settings, if they exist ?  I am not really confident what I am doing in the moment, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the preference file clearly states the name of the bundle that is using it. You are talking about org.eclipse.core.net.prefs meaning that the bundle using these properties is org.eclipse.core.net

You are talking about your OSGi application and Eclipse. Are you using Eclipse as an IDE to run your application or you have standalone OSGi application running in equinox?

In general the answer to your question is that if you need to have system variables for proxy e.g. **http.proxyHost** and **http.proxyPort** you will need to find out if you really need this **bundle** "**org.eclipse.core.net**".

If you do not need it just remove it from your launch configuration and the proxy settings will not be overwritten. If this is not possible try to configure it using the file you've mentioned "org.eclipse.core.net.prefs" or even better you can do it programmatically using **org.eclipse.core.net.proxy** package services.